# Having to agree to T&Cs on first run in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I was wondering if it would be possible to programmatically make users agree to the Terms of Service I have for my application, but for them only to have to agree to it the first time they run the app straight after downloading it, as Apple requires Terms and Conditions for a social networking type application. Any help would be much appreciated as it will be one of the deciding factors on whether my app makes it to the app store or not.

Comment: Yes, this is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a simple solution:

Put your to-be-called method in your delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, which means the T&C are shown to the user as soon as he starts the application. Then for the "once-in-a-lifetime" you could simple store a value in `NSUserDefault`(e.g. a string "`alreadySent`") at the end your custom method, which will persist over time as soon as the user doesn't delete application & data.

So the flow of event could be

1. App launch
2. Check: is the NSUserDefault value "`alreadySent`"?
3. No: Ok call method and show T&C
4. Yes: skip

This is a simple method which gives you a one-shot way to show the user what you want.

(Just google if you don't know how the `NSUserDefault` works, it's straightforward)